# Security error spawning web worker from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, web-worker, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm experimenting with web workers. I'm trying to spawn one from a firefox extension. From my `background.js`:

```
worker_path = browser.runtime.getURL("worker.js");
worker = new Worker(worker_path)

worker.postMessage(["hi"]);
```

From `worker.js`:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from main script');
}
```

From `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "description": "Test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "homepage_url": "http://example.com",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/icon.png"
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "example@me",
            "strict_min_version": "68.3"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://example.com/*", "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js",
            "worker.js"
        ]
    },
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "strict_min_version": "57.0a1"
        }
    }
}
```

Error in debug console: `SecurityError: Failed to load worker script at "moz-extension://myExtension@me/worker.js"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the fully qualified URL for a file inside my extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773773/how-do-i-get-the-fully-qualified-url-for-a-file-inside-my-extension)

Comment: You have hard coded the URL you're trying to open as your worker. That won't work. [`runtime.getURL()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getURL) exists because you don't know the URL which the browser is going to assign to your extension.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That solution doesn't apply (Or at least doesn't work). The same error happens.

Comment: Then show a [MRE] that duplicates the problem, include where in your extension the file is. For Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: At a minimum, please [edit] the question to show enough code to duplicate the problem, including a *manifest.json* and where in your extension, relative to your *manifest.json* your worker.js file is. At this point, it may be easier to ask a new question that includes enough information to duplicate the problem (and shows getting the URL, using `runtime.getURL()`). We do want to help, but you need to give us enough information so we *can* help.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: I just figured anyone who could help with an extension must know to put the js files in the manifest. I added it and updated the calling script.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate and probably referred you to a similar question that had answers. If those answers are tried or you know they won't work because your situation is different, please explain why or how your question is unique and un-answered and people may try to help.

Comment: The question referred to as duplicate does not have anything to do with this question. The answer to this question has to do with a bug filed with mozilla preventing web workers from working in firefox extensions. Nothing to do with fully qualified URLs. @clearlight